# Random effects, glmer, nested design

Tags: statistics

I have the following question:
I am analyzing the number of seed capsules between different genotypes (A,B and C)
I have 4 replicates for each genotype and in each of these replicates, I have 8 plants. Here is an example of the data:
Genotype    Replicate_ID    Plant_ID    Seed_capsules
A   1   1   6
A   1   2   10
A   1   3   15
B   2   1   100
B   2   2   40
B   2   3   63
C   3   1   80
C   3   2   90
C   3   3   100

I used the glmer on the data but I am not sure whether my random is the replicate_ID or the plant_ID or both. Here is an example of what I tried so far:
freplicate_ID  <- factor(newdata$replicate_ID)
fplant_ID <- factor(newdata$plant_ID)
m5 <- glmer(seed_capsules ~  pop_ID + (1| freplicate_ID /fplant_ID), family=poisson,data = data)

Further, How do I obtain the diagnostic plots for such a model? How do I compare between the genotypes? Do I need to run lsmeans on the model? Like this for example:
lsmeans(m5,pairwise ~ pop_ID, data=newdata) .
I thank you in advance for your help.
best,
Anna

Comment: please provide a reproducible snippet of the data. The way you present it makes it hard to follow.

Comment: Here is the link for the data and the question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218705/nested-glmms-which-are-my-random-factors